# Paste many excel charts to Word as links

Tags: c#, excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write C# code to Copy-Paste charts from Excel and use Paste Link in MS Word, because with Excel, when you use Paste Link for the tables, text, charts, etc. I can click update all fields in Word after you change anything in Excel.

I was trying to use OpenXML to add content controls in Word and paste the charts to those spots, like what this blogger does. 
http://www.dotblogs.com.tw/angus/archive/2010/05/19/15332.aspx

I added content control of the type "pictures" for each chart and they were successfully pasted in but not as links. Thus when I click "update links now" in Word after Excel data change, the charts in Word stay the same.

Maybe I didn't add the right type of content control? I don't know which type I should use for links.

Could any one point me to some source code or even a software?

Comment: Word supports "bookmarks" which should allow you to insert charts at specific points. I have a VBA routine that inserted charts as images (not OLEObjects, but you could probably modify that concept) at these bookmarks (and would "update" them on user prompt)  if you're interested I could post it for you to review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here:

**VBA:** [How to Programmatically Insert an Excel Chart into Word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176868).

**C#:** [Automating Word Tables for Data Insertion and Extraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa537149%28v=office.11%29.aspx#officewordautomatingtablesdata_linkingintables)

The magic does **PasteSpecial** method and its input parameter: **Link** set to **True** ;)

For further information, please see: [Link or embed an Excel worksheet](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/link-or-embed-an-excel-worksheet-HA010120810.aspx)